# Updating the Google search results text

Tags: google-search

I have a website that is being indexed by Google search. When I search for the site is shows up in my search results (5th) but the text being displayed to represent my site on the results page is very outdated. How can I tell the Google search engine that it needs to update (re-index) that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait patiently. Google reindexes on its own time. It with great frequency reindexes big sites with tons of changing content, and with very little frequency reindexes smaller sites that change less often.

Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: My home page has been updated months ago and there is still "old" copy being shown in the search results. I've properly set up my site with Google Webmaster tools (when I launched it initially) and I was hoping there would be an option in there to kinda "push" the search engine to update, but unfortunately.

Comment: Which query, site, and is it still happening?